# Чередование строк 1 через 2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

помогите, пожалуйста.

Прошу помочь скриптом, для Google Sheets, чтобы добавить после каждой строки таблицы, где в строке есть значения 2 пустые строки.

Было

| 1 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Стало

| 1 |
| --- |
| . |
| . |
| 2 |
| . |
| . |
| 3 |
| . |
| . |

Где точка это пустая строка.

@DiMithras
При выполнении скрипта выдаётся ошибка.
Exception: Формат 01.02.2019
Содержимое таблицы разное, в ней около 100 столбцов, может больше.
Нужно, чтобы строки пустые добавило после каждой строки независимо от от содержимого.
Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Идём в Extensions → AppsScript

Создаём новый проект

```js
function addEmptyRowsAfterEachRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numRows = data.length;
  var numCols = data[0].length;
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    output.push(data[i]);
    output.push(Array(numCols).fill(""));
    output.push(Array(numCols).fill(""));
  }

  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

Сохраняем, запускаем при открытой Google таблице.

[image: Демонстрация работы в Google Sheets]

---

Я не могу протестировать ваши сценарии, но пусть так будет:

```js
function addEmptyRowsAfterEachRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numRows = data.length;
  var numCols = data[0].length;
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (isValidRow(row)) {
      output.push(row);
      output.push(Array(numCols).fill(""));
      output.push(Array(numCols).fill(""));
    }
  }

  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}

function isValidRow(row) {
  return !isNaN(row[0]);
}
```

Comment: Exception: Формат 01.02.2019Свойства
Какую-то ошибку выдало

Comment: @Евгений я не знаю содержания вашего google sheets, для 1,2,3 работает без ошибок.

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, что я могу сделать, чтобы этого не было? Можно ли сделать, чтобы не учитывало содержимого? Спасибо

Comment: Можно. Какое у вас содержимое? И добавьте нормально в вопрос ошибку вашу.

Comment: При выполнении скрипта выдаётся ошибка.
Exception: Формат 01.02.2019
Содержимое таблицы разное, в ней около 100 столбцов, может больше.
Нужно, чтобы строки пустые добавило после каждой строки независимо от от содержимого.
Спасибо.

Comment: @contributorpw не совсем так. В вопросе изначально цифры указаны и вопрос был самодостаточен.